# CURDATE() causes an syntax error

Tags: mysql, database

everyone

I wanna add a column start_date whose default value is current date(), so I use following commands:

**alter table validation add column start_date date default CURDATE()**

but it didn't work and told me it has syntax error.

While using such following command works well:

**alter table validation add column start_date date default 0**

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html) (my bold):

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value **must** be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.
>
> This means, for example, that you **cannot** set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE.
>
> The exception is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

That's why `default 0` works (a constant) but `default curdate()` doesn't (a function).

You have (at least) a couple of possibilities to work around this.

The first is to use a timestamp column instead of a date column, and set its default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Unfortunately, that means you'll have to turn that back into a date when extracting it.

The second is to use triggers to set the column value, rather than from a default value. For example, use an insert trigger to set the relevant column to the current date.

Comment: Ahah, I just posted the same exact answer (even the "bold is mine" part!). You beat me by 1 min though, so I will remove mine

Answer (score 0):

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try SYSDATE().

```
Select SYSDATE();
```

This will give you in this format: `2011-09-29 16:11:39`

Comment: That is not what the OP is asking